# CustomView's "onDraw()"-Method never gets called

Tags: android, layout, view, rendering

Here's a tricky one:

I'm writing my custom `ImageView`:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View
```

The picture to display is set via `setImagePath(String path)` and the `BitMap` loaded inside from the `assets` folder. That's working pretty fine, image dimensions are verified.

In later progress, the `CustomImageView`-Object is added to a `LinearLayout` (matches parent) via `addView(View v)`. The overridden method

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

gets called and calculates some loony values, nothing important at this point.

The weird thing is that the *bottom value* always is *zero*! And I think thats the point why `onDraw(Canvas c)` never gets called.

```
E/CIView﹕ onLayout - changed: true, left: 0, top: 0, right: 1080, bottom: 0
E/CIView﹕ bitmap - bitmapWidth: 735, bitmapHeight: 490
E/CIView﹕ onLayout - changed: false, left: 0, top: 0, right: 1080, bottom: 0
E/CIView﹕ bitmap - bitmapWidth: 735, bitmapHeight: 490
```

Can anybody explain to me why `onLayout` never gets the right bottom-value? Methods like `invalidate()` or `requestLayout()` didn't change anything, maybe I missed some special part..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `View` you need to provide its size - which is why you're getting zero height bounds. So implement `onMeasure()` and inside that call `setMeasuredDimension()`.

E.g.

`@Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {

        setMeasuredDimension(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
    }`

Though you should check that there is enough space using

`MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)` and

`MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)`

Comment: Using bitmap's width and height for setMeasuredDimension() did the trick! thanks :)